pypapi.exceptions.PapiInvalidValueError: Invalid Argument. (PAPI_EINVAL)
Got the following error when tried to run code from pypapi.. Made sure that I have access to the event (PAPI_FP_OPS).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/pypapi/test_pypapi.py", line 24, in <module>
    **high.hl_region_begin("computation")**
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/dist-packages/pypapi/exceptions.py", line 197, in papi_error_wrapper
    raise object_()
pypapi.exceptions.PapiInvalidValueError: Invalid Argument. (PAPI_EINVAL)

